# Highlight label in red if any field in group isn't valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate to validate a form, and i've got the following:

```
$.validator.messages.required = ' *';

errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    $( element )
        .closest( "form" )
        .find( "label[for='" + element.attr( "id" ) + "']" )
        .append( error );
    },
errorElement: "span",
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
   $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
   .addClass("error");
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]")
    .removeClass("error");
},
```

Which perfectly highlights my field labels in red and puts a * next to them. However I have an issue that when I have a group of fields, currently the field label only turns red if the first field is invalid (obviously as the label is for that field).

Could anyone tell me how to make the label turn red for any item in that group of fields? So if month or year is invalid in a date of birth group?

EDIT: JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9dqrtpy/

Comment: Can you include an example of your markup?

Comment: If you enter the content for day wrongly, it highlights the label in red, but if you do the same for month, it just puts a red *... http://jsfiddle.net/v9dqrtpy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it's not in the spec, a quick test shows this quick workaround is effective (in Chrome/Firefox on Linux, anyway):

```
<label for="dobday"><label for="dobmonth"><label for="dobyear">Date of Birth</label></label></label>
```

The problem is that it's changing the color of the input and the label for that input (based on ID attr). You should probably wrap the label around the elements, and check if $(input).parents('label') exists and assume it's a field group. You could apply similar logic  to a legend/fieldset pair and make standards people happy. (Determine if the field belongs to a fieldset or not, and do the appropriate thing.)

http://jsfiddle.net/v9dqrtpy/3/

Comment: That's perfect and great explanation. Cheers Curtis.

Comment: I've found a slight issue that I'm wondering if you know a solution to?

For some reason if I click submit without having filled any of the date of birth fields in the error span is inside all 3 of the labels, however if I complete the first field correctly, the second one incorrectly, the span jumps outside of the span that was done correctly and the * appears on the next line.

Comment: I modified the errorPlacement code to use a separate rule. I think this solves the issue you're referring to: http://jsfiddle.net/v9dqrtpy/4/